# HTTP Server on non-standard port

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

I have an application running on my local network (localhost).  I want to connect to some external sever (outside of my local network) on a non-standard port.

The only way I can think of is to create an EC2 instance and have a nodejs server running on port 1024 for example.

The problem with this is that I don't want the expensive cost of an EC2 instance for a server that I will be using very sporadically. I don't think I can run a lambda on a specific port or create an api in api gateway to be served over a specific port.

Do you know what will be the best way to run some server on a specific port? The only thing I need is an OK response. I just need to make sure that I can make a connection from my app to a service outside of my local network running on a non-standard port.

Comment: If I understand your question an API gateway, in front of a Lambda could connect to your remote server on any port you'd like.  The API Gateway/Lambda combo would act as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say maybe you are looking for [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

It lets you expose a secure port to something that is hosted locally.

> I just need to make sure that I can make a connection from my app to a service outside of my local network running on a non-standard port.

Could you clarify on the application here? Are you just trying to check that there is a connection to an outside resource? If so, then you could just ping almost any external resource and see if you get a 200 back.

Comment: I don't want to use ngrok. This eventually will need to be used from a device I'm distributing to end users. I basically need to build something like http://portquiz.net:332

however I don't want a server runnning all the time as I don't expect much usage. I want something serverless, but with the ability to run on a non 80/443 port